# Regular expression matching (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got the following string: `|Africa||Africans||African Society||Go Africa Go||Mafricano||Go Mafricano Go||West Africa|`.

I am trying to write a regular expression that only matches terms that include the word `Africa` or any deriative of it (meaning yes to all terms above except for `|Mafricano|` and `|Go Mafricano Go|`. Each term is enclosed between two `|`.

Right now I've come up with: `/\|[^\|]*africa[^\|]*\|/gi`, which says:

---

1. `\|`
   Match `|`

---

2. `[^\|]*`
   Match zero to unlimited instances of any character except `|`

---

3. `africa`
   Match `africa` literally

---

4. `[^\|]*`
   Match zero to unlimited instances of any character except `|`

---

5. `\|`
   Match `|`

---

I've tried inserting `((?:\s)|(?!\w))` to make it `/\|[^\|]*((?:\s)|(?!\w))africa[^\|]*\|/gi`. Although it succeeds in excluding `|Mafricano|` and `|Go Mafricano Go|`, it also excludes all other entries except for `|West Africa|` and `|Go Africa Go|`. So that is good but it needs to include all single word `Africa` and its derived forms too.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: why don't you use `replace` ? It should be much more easier.

Comment: @JhKaiz, @AvinashRaj: I need an array of all matched terms, so I'll be using the `match()` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
[^|]*\bAfrica[a-z]*\b[^|]*
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/nU0cA2/1)

```
var str = "|Africa||Africans||African Society||Go Africa Go||Mafricano||Go Mafricano Go||West Africa|";
var arr = str.match(/[^|]*\bAfrica[a-z]*\b[^|]*/g);
console.log(arr); // ["Africa", "Africans", "African Society", "Go Africa Go", "West Africa"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this,

```
\|(?:(?!Mafrica|\|).)*?africa(?:(?!Mafrica|\|).)*?\|
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zE5tH7/2)

```
> "|Africa||Africans||African Society||Go Africa Go||Mafricano||Go Mafricano Go||West Africa|".match(/\|(?:(?!Mafrica|\|).)*?africa(?:(?!Mafrica|\|).)*?\|/gi);
[ '|Africa|',
  '|Africans|',
  '|African Society|',
  '|Go Africa Go|',
  '|West Africa|' ]
```

Don't forget to turn on the `i`  modifier to do a case insensitive match.

**Explanation:**

```
\|                       '|'
(?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                         times):
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
    Mafrica                  'Mafrica'
   |                        OR
    \|                       '|'
  )                        end of look-ahead
  .                        any character except \n
)*?                      end of grouping
africa                   'africa'
(?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                         times):
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
    Mafrica                  'Mafrica'
   |                        OR
    \|                       '|'
  )                        end of look-ahead
  .                        any character except \n
)*?                      end of grouping
\|                       '|'
```

Comment: The entries are way more diverse and more random than `Mafricano`, so this would not scale for other entries. Thanks though.

Comment: My apologies for that. I thought that was implied.

Comment: You're welcome.. Next time don't forget to to post a question with detailed explanation on very first.